# Optimizing Redis Lua script calls to redis.call

Tags: redis, lua

According to this Lua optimization doc: https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf

> Access to external locals (that is, variables that are local to an
> enclosing function) is not as fast as access to local variables, but
> it is still faster than access to globals. Consider the next fragment:

```
function foo (x)
  for i = 1, 1000000 do
    x = x + math.sin(i)
  end
  return x
end
print(foo(10))
```

> We can optimize it by declaring sin once, outside function foo: local

```
sin = math.sin
function foo (x)
  for i = 1, 1000000 do
    x = x + sin(i)
  end
  return x
end
print(foo(10))
```

**Is `redis.call` a *global*? Can we optimize it by delcaring a local variable pointing to it? Especially for tight loops that call `redis.call` many times.**

**And as a follow up are `KEYS` and `ARGV` also *globals*?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is redis.call a global?

> And as a follow up are KEYS and ARGV also globals?

Yes, *redis*, *KEYS* and *ARGV* are globals.

> Can we optimize it by delcaring a local variable pointing to it? Especially for tight loops that call redis.call many times.

According to your reference, it seems you can optimize the Lua code with local vars. However, normally you should not run too many operations in Lua script, e.g. run a large loop and execute many redis commands. Because Redis is single-threaded, if Lua script takes too much time, it will block Redis.

Normally, I'd like to assign elements in KEYS and ARGV array, to local vars. Not for efficiency, but for code clarity.

Comment: Would a loop that executes about 800 times be considered too large. I checked the time of each script execution by decreasing the slowlog threshold, and each execution is around 2 to 3 milliseconds at most - not microseconds. Is that typically to slow?

Comment: YES, it's slow. Normally an execution, including network stuff, should be finished in microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

So the following three Redis commands all execute successfully.

1. `eval "return _G.redis.call('set', 'x', 1)" 0`
2. `eval "return _G.KEYS" 1 1`
3. `eval "return _G.ARGV" 0 1`

So I'm guessing they're all globals. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong...